# As soon as I try to include a file inside a folder, my relative paths break?

Tags: php, ubuntu, include, include-path

Just wondering what I'm doing wrong here. I've been setting up a linux dev environment. If I do something like this:

```
include 'test.php';
```

It works great.

If I then move my test.php file into a folder called test and do this:

```
include 'test/test.php';
```

It fails. What is going on?

I have also tried:

```
include '/var/www/site/test/test.php';
include '/test/test.php';
include '../test/test.php';
```

etc, with no luck.

Comment: Maybe you're using some kind of url rewriting?

Comment: permissions may be wrong

Comment: Please give the error. The syntax seems right.

Comment: Inside the file you are attempting to include from, place `echo getcwd();` and let us know what the current working directory is.

Comment: 'test/' is in the root folder, while 'test.php' is in the current (including, called/started) folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder containing you include file (and any other nested folders you ask php engine to access) should have its executable flag set.

In a linux terminal:

```
chmod a+x /var/www/site/test
```

to check permissions:

```
ls -l /var/www/site | grep "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try `require('test/test.php');` ?